# Codeplex SVN $Author$ Property problem

Tags: svn, codeplex

I'm trying to setup a codeplex project, but I can't make the $Author$ property for the commit to work. Both $Author$ and $LastChangedBy$ returns "unknown" when committing to CodePlex.

I enabled the property though AnkhSvn in Visual Studio 2008.

Any idea if it's something I can fix myself, or is it a bug with the TFS bridge?

Comment: If people would bother to read the question, specially the part where I explicit writes it's related to CodePlex (both in title and question), it would be much helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyword expansion is actually done by the client, not the server. I'd give it a shot with a different svn client (preferably the official command line one) to see if it works for you there. Don't forget to set your props on the project.

If you're not getting responses for the queries used by the client to get the data used to fill the fields (this will likely take some traces), then I'd suspect an issue with the bridge, bu otherwise I'd guess it's likely a client issue.

Comment: Well, I Date and Revision works, so why wouldn't Author work? I've been told the value of the $Author$ is set by the server, since it's not the client that holds track of who commited.

Comment: If I'm recalling correctly Author is set by the client based upon a svnlook at the server.  I'll admit I could e wrong about that, as I'm relying on memory from an svnusers list post many years ago. If your svn server is a separate host, my personal approach would be to first grab packets to see if you're actually receiving a valid result.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the **keywords** property, along with the actual keywords you want to use?

The property consists of a list of the particular keywords you want activated for keyword substitution.

see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html